# Where is the URL Rewrite options in IIS 6.2?

Tags: url-rewriting, iis6

I am trying to set a **replica** of an existing (production!) web site of my new employer on my local machine. By replica I mean: "as close of possible" in terms of versions (IIS, PHP, MySQL, WordPress, etc.).

The problem is... the production's IIS is 6.0, whereas my workstation's is 6.2.

The productions IIS 6.0 management console looks like this:

[image]

My machines (local) IIS 6.2 management console looks like this:

[image]

My question is: How do I implement URL rewrite on my local IIS?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer!

Sharing it for the benefit of future IIS newbies:

Go to http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite , download & install it from there. That's it.

Comment: That is for IIS 7, no IIS6.